# Image not showing in Toolbar in Android Studio (Flamingo)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview

I am facing a problem to show images and TextView in Custom Toolbar.
I have this Layout structure.

RelativeLayout -> androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar -> LinearLayout(horizontal) -> ImageView,TextView.

Also, I got built-In ActionBar in project and i used

````
getSupportActionBar().hide();
``` to remove it.

here is the complete XML code.

I have checked on both virtual and physical device but images and text of toolbar not showing.
````

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/camera"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bilbo_swash_caps"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/instagram"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="InefficientWeight,TextSizeCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/instatv" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:tint="@color/textcolor"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/send"
            tools:ignore="UseAppTint" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

```

I have used

```
android:src
```

```
app:srcCompat
```

```
android:foreground
```

```
android:background
```

I have also change the colors to see the difference but even changing the color in toolbar is not working.

It is the values\themes.xml code

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

-->

```
</style>
```

And it is the night\themes.xml code

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

That is the message I got as a warning for Toolbar. And for that reason when I was trying to do anything with the toolbar it was not effected.

This check finds attributes set in XML files that were introduced in a version newer than the oldest version targeted by your application (with the minSdkVersion attribute).  This is not an error; the application will simply ignore the attribute. However, if the attribute is important to the appearance or functionality of your application, you should consider finding an alternative way to achieve the same result with only available attributes, and then you can optionally create a copy of the layout in a layout-vNN folder which will be used on API NN or higher where you can take advantage of the newer attribute.  Note: This check does not only apply to attributes. For example, some tags can be unused too, such as the new  element in layouts introduced in API 21.

Comment: Anyone ??????????

Comment: your approach is a little wrong for hiding the action bar change parent in in your `theme.xml` to `<style name="Theme.<Your App Theme>" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">`  by doing so you don't need to use getSupportActionBar.hide() also check your theme.xml maybe you're having issues with colors

Comment: @GhazanfarAteeb By doing so app is not running.  I have also added themes.xml up there plz look into that

Comment: Hi @SarmadAli, I have added your XML-code to my test project. And here's what [it looks like for me](https://imgur.com/DALLt2x). I replaced only the icons. Everything seems to be working correctly. Do you also see it or not?

Comment: //        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
//        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
//        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

Comment: i have removed above code from MainActivity.java now app is running but still images are not visible in toolbar. images are 64x64 and in png. i have also replaced images with the android-icon but still not working.

Comment: And i i don't know if this information is necessary, I have used Bottom Navigation Views Activity template for that project.

Comment: @IvanAbakumov it's visible on the design but not in virtual or physical devices when I run the app.

Comment: [checked on a physical device](https://imgur.com/ORzb7z9). Also works correctly.
Can you add the class code to which your code is bound?
As well as the structure of the project. Do you have one activity?

Comment: Please see a warning I have attached with the question.

Comment: @IvanAbakumov Sir I am using Bottom Navigation View Activity Template for the project. There are other activities and other fragments as well. but i have just edited Home fragment and activity_main.xml

Comment: Can you upload the code to Github?

Comment: @IvanAbakumov Here is the link to the code https://github.com/sarmadalij/Instagram

Comment: And yes, when i was inspecting the layout, I selected my physical device for inspection and then layout-v21 folder was created under res that contain the same activity_main.xml when i edited it little bit it starts to show the image but when i am trying to do through the actual activity_main.xml it doesn't effect it. is it related to some version things? I am new please guide, and how i can do it just in main activity_main.xml ?

Comment: What device version are you testing on?

Comment: It's Infinix Hot 10, model: Infinix X682B, Android Version 10. And the folder that was created when inspecting layout is v21, is it API Level ?

Comment: @SarmadAli
A **res/layout-v21/** directory contains resources that will be used when the device that is running your app is on API Level 21 or higher. If the device is running on an older version of Android, **the res/layout-v21/** directory will be ignored.

Comment: I also ran your code from **Github** and everything works fine for me. So I don't understand what your problem is